# Sphere immersions in 4-manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, spheres

I'm having trouble understanding the homomorphisms $\pi_1g(S^2)\longrightarrow \pi_1 M^4$ where $g: S^2\longrightarrow M^4$ can be a framed or unframed immersion.

Any reference on this?

Comment: You typically learn this in an algebraic topology class/textbook: A continuous map of pointed topological spaces $(X,x)\to (Y,y)$ induces a homomorphism $\pi_1(X,x)\to \pi_1(Y,y)$. The extra assumptions ($g$ is an immersion etc) are irrelevant here. In your case, $X=S^2$ is simply-connected, hence, your homomorphism is trivial. My suggestion is to read Chapter 1.1 of Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology".

Comment: No, my homomorphism is $\pi_1g(S^2)\rightlongarrow\pi_1M. The immersed sphere would have finitely many self intersections.@MoisheKohan